# How do I find connection device names to nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to find the name of the device that is connected via http to nodejs servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the user agent string in the http request. There are also packages in npm for user agent sniffing.

Comment: The user agent doesn't tell me the device name. Am I missing something?

Comment: I missunderstood, I believed you wanted to know how to get the name of the device type, not the device instance. That information is not it the http-header, so it's not available to the server. If you controll the page sending the request you could add the information to the request, but you're still limited to the information that the browser has access to.